# SQL to delete the value from a column where both columns exist

Tags: sql, sqlite

Is this correct? Will it work with Sqlite as well?

```
 UPDATE table SET oldCol=NULL WHERE (oldCol!=NULL AND newCol!=NULL)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you should use `is not null`:

```
update tbl set oldcol = null where oldcol is not null and newcol is not null
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use this also.
UPDATE table SET oldCol=NULL WHERE (oldCol is not NULL AND newCol is not  NULL)